# Restoring real window size in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, window, maximize

I'm trying to implement storing and restoring main window state and size in my WPF application. My current code looks like following:

- MainWindowViewModel.cs (ran on main window's `OnLoaded`):

  ```
  public void NotifyLoaded()
  {
      var uiConfig = configurationService.Configuration.UI;

      if (uiConfig.MainWindowSizeSet.Value)
          access.SetWindowSize(new System.Windows.Size(uiConfig.MainWindowWidth.Value, 
              uiConfig.MainWindowHeight.Value));

      if (uiConfig.MainWindowLocationSet.Value)
          access.SetWindowLocation(new System.Windows.Point(uiConfig.MainWindowX.Value,
              uiConfig.MainWindowY.Value));

      if (uiConfig.MainWindowMaximized.Value)
          access.SetWindowMaximized(true);
  }
  ```
- The `access` is an `IMainWindowAccess`, implemented by the `MainWindow` itself (this is my way of providing communication between viewmodel and window, while still keeping logic and view separated). Methods are being implemented in the following way:

  ```
  void IMainWindowAccess.SetWindowSize(Size size)
  {
      this.Width = size.Width;
      this.Height = size.Height;
  }

  void IMainWindowAccess.SetWindowLocation(Point point)
  {
      this.Left = point.X;
      this.Top = point.Y;
  }

  void IMainWindowAccess.SetWindowMaximized(bool maximized)
  {
      this.WindowState = maximized ? WindowState.Maximized : WindowState.Normal;
  }
  ```
- I'm storing window position and size on window closing, but only if window is not maximized. I do that to avoid situation when user tries to restore window and it restores to its maximized size.

  ```
  public void NotifyClosingWindow()
  {
      var windowSize = access.GetWindowSize();
      var windowLocation = access.GetWindowLocation();

      var maximized = access.GetMaximized();
      configurationService.Configuration.UI.MainWindowMaximized.Value = maximized;

      if (!maximized)
      {
          Models.Configuration.UI.UIConfig uiConfig = configurationService.Configuration.UI;

          uiConfig.MainWindowWidth.Value = windowSize.Width;
          uiConfig.MainWindowHeight.Value = windowSize.Height;
          uiConfig.MainWindowSizeSet.Value = true;

          uiConfig.MainWindowX.Value = windowLocation.X;
          uiConfig.MainWindowY.Value = windowLocation.Y;
          uiConfig.MainWindowLocationSet.Value = true;
      }

      configurationService.Save();
  }
  ```

The problem is that though I restore size and location of the window before maximizing it (so it *should* restore to its former size), it still restores to maximized size (effectively clicking the restore button changes button to maximize - size and location remains the same).

How should I set size and location of the window and then maximize it, so that size and location will be properly stored?

Comment: Have you tried to manage `Window.StateChanged` event?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows

```
// RECT structure required by WINDOWPLACEMENT structure
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;

    public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        Left = left;
        Top = top;
        Right = right;
        Bottom = bottom;
    }
}

// POINT structure required by WINDOWPLACEMENT structure
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public POINT(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

// WINDOWPLACEMENT stores the position, size, and state of a window
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
{
    public int length;
    public int flags;
    public int showCmd;
    public POINT minPosition;
    public POINT maxPosition;
    public RECT normalPosition;
}
```

and

```
public static class WindowRestorerService
{
    private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
    private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;

    private static Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    private static XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT));

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, [In] ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, out WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    public static void SetPlacement(this Window window, string placementXml)
    {
        WindowRestorerService.SetPlacement(new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle, placementXml);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the window to the relevent position using the placement information. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="windowHandle">The window handle of the target information.</param>
    /// <param name="placementXml">The placement XML.</param>
    public static void SetPlacement(IntPtr windowHandle, string placementXml)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(placementXml))
            return;

        WINDOWPLACEMENT placement;
        byte[] xmlBytes = encoding.GetBytes(placementXml);

        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(xmlBytes))
            {
                placement = (WINDOWPLACEMENT)serializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
            }

            placement.length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT));
            placement.flags = 0;
            placement.showCmd = (placement.showCmd == SW_SHOWMINIMIZED ? SW_SHOWNORMAL : placement.showCmd);
            SetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, ref placement);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            // Parsing placement XML failed. Fail silently.
        }
    }

    public static string GetPlacement(this Window window)
    {
        return WindowRestorerService.GetPlacement(new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retruns the serialize XML of the placement information for the 
    /// target window.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="windowHandle">The handle of the target window.</param>
    public static string GetPlacement(IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
        WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
        GetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, out placement);

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, placement);
                byte[] xmlBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                return encoding.GetString(xmlBytes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Store position on close (I'm storing this info in my settings file)

```
public void OnClosing()
{
    MainWindowSettingsProvider settingsProvider = MainWindowSettingsProvider.Instance;
    settingsProvider.MainWindowSettings.WindowPlacementInfo = ((Window)View).GetPlacement();
    settingsProvider.Save();
}
```

And set via

```
[Export(typeof(IMainWindowView))]
public partial class MainWindowView : MetroWindow, IMainWindowView
{
    public MainWindowView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        MainWindowSettingsProvider settingsProvider = MainWindowSettingsProvider.Instance;
        this.SetPlacement(settingsProvider.MainWindowSettings.WindowPlacementInfo);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the Nuget project [RestoreWindowPlace](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestoreWindowPlace) which handles this for you.

Just register in your App.xaml.cs:

```
public WindowPlace WindowPlace { get; }

public App()
{
    this.WindowPlace = new WindowPlace("WindowPlacement.config");
}
```

and put this in your Window's xaml:

```
((App)Application.Current).WindowPlace.Register(this);
```

It stores the data in a xml-file.